# How to use "this" to access class in Java

Tags: java

I understand using "this" returns different objects based on the scope you're currently in. How would I return the reference to my class, and not the function in this particular scenario?

```
public void create() {

    // Creates 10 second clock and timer that warps the teams to their respective maps to begin.
    map_factory.getMap(waiting_map).broadcastMessage(MaplePacketCreator.getClock(10));

    // Warps players to respective maps to begin the PQ.
    // Starts the scheduler to start spawning initial mobs.
    // Sets a timer for 10 minutes; after 10 minutes the end function will execute and end the game.
    this.schedule = TimerManager.getInstance().schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            blue_party.warpParty(blue_map);
            red_party.warpParty(red_map);
            start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            execute();
            startTimer();
        }
    }, 10000);


}
```

This function is within my class. I'm trying to set **start_time** to the current time in milliseconds, but that just creates a local variable. **start_time** is actually a class variable. I wasn't sure what kind of syntax I would have to use to look up a question like this, so I thought it would be easier to ask. Perhaps a more testable example would be this:

```
public void foo() {
    this.schedule = TimerManager.getInstance().schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: this does not create a local variable as you did not specify the type of the variable, it should work. If you want to use `this` use `MyClass.this.start_time`

Comment: how about: return this; ?

Comment: Oh, you're very right @Hacketo. I think I just got blind-sided by my editor telling me that the variable was unused.

Comment: And thank you that was exactly what I was looking for.